# Generate random numbers and check for duplicates

Tags: swift, duplicates

I want to know if there is an easy way to check for duplicates amongst six different random numbers. I want to check if 4+ of the 6 random numbers are the same to create an if-statement.

For example;

```
let firstRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
let secondRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
let thirdRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
let fourthRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
let fifthRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
let sixthRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
```

With these random numbers I want to execute and action if four or more of them are the same (for example `3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1`. ) Anyone know how?

Comment: What do you mean with `more than four duplicates`? Give me an example of the input and of the output. E.g. this input `[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2]` what output should determine?

Comment: If, for example, `[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]` - **If four of the six random generated numbers are the same**

Comment: Ok. You want to know if the same number does appear at least 4 times. Thanks.

Comment: @appzYourLife Yes, thank you for noticing my bad explanation. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this

```
let allValues = [firstRandomNumber,secondRandomNumber, thirdRandomNumber, fourthRandomNumber,fifthRandomNumber, sixthRandomNumber]

let maxOccurrencies:(value:UInt32, times:Int)? = allValues
    .reduce([UInt32:Int]()) { (var dict, elm) -> [UInt32:Int] in
        dict[elm] = (dict[elm] ?? 0) + 1
        return dict
    }
    .maxElement { $0.1 < $1.1 }


if let (value, times) = maxOccurrencies where times >= 4 {
    print("The value \(value) does appear \(times) times")
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I can't be thankful enough, people like you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat shorter solution :

```
let numbers      = [3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]

let counts       = numbers.map({ (N) in numbers.filter({ $0 == N }).count })
let fourOrMore   = counts.contains({ $0 >= 4 })

if fourOrMore  { print(" there are more than four identical values") }
```

and an even shorter one:

```
let numbers      = [3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]

if numbers.contains({ (N) in numbers.filter({$0 == N}).count >= 4 })
{ print(" there are more than four identical values") }
```